# Users who like you back (EXISTS) that you have not chatted with (NOT EXISTS)

Tags: sql, postgresql

If you is `"t1".persona_1_id = 2`, the expected result should return `persona_id = 4`.

```
like
---
id persona_1_id persona_2_id liked
1  2            1            FALSE
2  3            1            TRUE
3  4            2            TRUE  -- 4 likes 2
4  2            4            TRUE  -- 2 likes 4
                                   -- (2 and 4 like each other)

chat_persona
---
id chat_id persona_id  -- but same chat has not been created between 2 and 4
1  1       3
2  1       2
3  2       4
4  2       1
5  3       5
6  3       1

-- so persona_id = 4 is the answer
```

I am trying to return the users that like each other, that do not have a chat between them already.

The "likes each other" works, but I am having additionally filtering for the "chat does not exist already":

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    "t1".id, "t1".read_at as read_at, "t1".created_at as created_at,
    "persona".id as persona_id, "persona".profile_id as profile_id, "persona".name as persona_name, "chat_persona".chat_id as chat_id, "chat_persona".id  as chat_persona_id
                    FROM "like" as "t1"
                        JOIN "persona" ON "t1".persona_2_id = "persona".id
                        JOIN "chat_persona" on "t1".persona_2_id = "chat_persona".persona_id
                    WHERE
                        "t1".persona_1_id = 2
                        AND EXISTS (
                            SELECT 1 
                            FROM "like" as "t2"
                            WHERE 
                                "t1".persona_1_id = "t2".persona_2_id 
                                AND "t1".persona_2_id = "t2".persona_1_id
                                AND "t2".liked = true
                        )
                        AND "t1".liked = true
                        AND "chat_persona".id IS NULL -- throws out the correct rows if ANY person chatted with them already... make sense
```

Instead of `AND "chat_persona".id IS NULL`, have also tried:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT 1 
                            FROM "chat_persona" as "t2"
                            WHERE 
                                "t1".persona_1_id = "t2".persona_id 
                                AND "t1".persona_2_id = "t2".persona_id
                        ) -- doesn't throw out any rows
```

---

Final answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    "l1".id, "l1".read_at as read_at, "l1".created_at as created_at,
    "persona".id as persona_id, "persona".profile_id as profile_id, "persona".name as persona_name
                    FROM "like" l1
                    JOIN "persona" ON "l1".persona_2_id = "persona".id
                    WHERE
                        "l1".persona_1_id = 2
                        AND "l1".liked = true
                        AND EXISTS (
                            SELECT 1 
                            FROM "like" l2
                            WHERE 
                                "l1".persona_1_id = "l2".persona_2_id 
                                AND "l1".persona_2_id = "l2".persona_1_id
                                AND "l2".liked = true
                        )
                        AND NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT 1
                            FROM "chat_persona" c
                            WHERE c.persona_id IN ("l1".persona_1_id, "l1".persona_2_id) 
                            GROUP BY c.chat_id
                            HAVING count(*) = 2
                        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking `not exists`, with a subquery that checks if both are in the same `chat`:

```
select l.persona_1_id, l.persona_2_id
from l
where not exists (select 1
                  from chats c
                  where c.persona_id in (l.persona_1_id, l.persona_2_id)
                  group by c.chat_id
                  having count(*) = 2  -- both are in chat
                 );
```

Comment: That did the trick for "chat does not exist"! I just had to add the "likes each other" back, and updated my original post with the end query. Hope that looks correct to you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have postgres on my machine, tested on SQL server and it gives the rows where you don't have chat and gives 4 as Person ID .

You may have to modify your query in this way. I modified few joins and changed exists to not exists and changed the inner query. You can see the solution in SQL server, concept should be same.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    "t1".id, "t1".read_at as read_at, "t1".created_at as created_at,
    "persona".id as persona_id, "persona".profile_id as profile_id, "persona".name as persona_name, "chat_persona".chat_id as chat_id, "chat_persona".id  as chat_persona_id
                    FROM "like" as "t1"
                        JOIN "persona" ON "t1".persona_2_id = "persona".id
                     --   JOIN "chat_persona" on "t1".persona_2_id = -- 
                    --"chat_persona".persona_id   --removed this join as you are looking 
                    --for the records that don't have chat 
                    WHERE
                        "t1".liked = true --changed it here 
                        AND not EXISTS (
                            SELECT 1 
                            FROM "chat_persona" as "t2" --changed it here 
                            WHERE 
                                "t2".Chat_ID = "t1".persona_1_id 
                                AND "t2".Persona_ID = "t1".persona_2_id

                        )
```

SQL server query:

```
 select 1 as ID, 2 as   persona_1_id,  1 as persona_2_id, 'FALSE' as Liked into #templike  union all 
select 2 as ID, 3 as   persona_1_id,  1 as persona_2_id, 'TRUE'  as Liked union all 
select 3 as ID, 4 as   persona_1_id,  2 as persona_2_id, 'TRUE'  as Liked union all   
select 4 as ID, 2 as   persona_1_id,  4 as persona_2_id, 'TRUE'  as Liked  


select 1 as ID, 1 as Chat_ID, 3 as Persona_ID into #chat_persona union all
select 2 as ID, 1 as Chat_ID, 2 as Persona_ID union all
select 3 as ID, 2 as Chat_ID, 4 as Persona_ID union all
select 4 as ID, 2 as Chat_ID, 1 as Persona_ID union all
select 5 as ID, 3 as Chat_ID, 5 as Persona_ID union all
select 6 as ID, 3 as Chat_ID, 1 as Persona_ID  

select * from #templike t 
where Liked = 'TRUE' and  not exists (select 1 from #chat_persona cp where cp.Chat_ID = t.persona_1_id and  cp.Persona_ID = t.persona_2_id)
```

Output:

```
ID  persona_1_id    persona_2_id    Liked
3   4                     2          TRUE
```

Comment: The first `EXISTS` already works and seems necessary for the mutual like. If it is not used, it seems to return rows where 2 likes them, even if they do not like 2 back. So if (2,1,true), 1 will get returned even though there is no (1,2,true). I am looking for "2 likes them, and they like 2 back, and 2 does not have a chat with them already".

Comment: But thank you, the join to `chat_persona` was absolutely unnecessary.